# Ошибки при обновлении пакетов

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> Системный кэш AppStream обновлён, но найдены проблемы: Файлы
>   метаданных содержат ошибки: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
>
> Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
>
> E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if
>   /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then
>   appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
>
> E: Sub-process returned an error code

Как это исправить?

Comment: Это StackOverflow на русском. Переведите, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894519/ubuntu-16-04-appstreamcli-error-while-get-update

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/14402526

Comment: @KAGGDesign откати предложение закрыть вопрос

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge

Comment: @Pero в google есть множество страниц с рецептами устранения этой проблемы